# Images on DataGridView cells according the variable stored. How to do it?

Tags: c#, .net

I need some help with my code. I've an already done and working DataGridView, however, at the first column cell I store a byte variable with range of 3 (0, 1 or 2).

I have too 3 ico pictures (16 x 16px) each one with a different color. I wanna see on the cell instead the values (0, 1 and 2) the pictures (red, green and yellow).

Please help me!

Thanks

Leo

Comment: Thanks guys! I solve this issue using a solution I found at msdn and added a switch statement: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ab8kd75.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If ur gridview is bound to some datasource then u can extend the data source to add an image column which will return image based on the byte column. for example if gridview is bound to entities then u can add a new property in ur entity class

```
 public Image Image {  get {   if(ByteValue == 0) return ZeroImage;    else if(ByteValue == 1) return OneImage; else  return TwoImage; } }
```

Or u can handle rowCreated event to provide the Image dependeing on the Byte Value

Answer (score 0):

Try this event

```
private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
  int imageIndex =  Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);
  switch (imageIndex)
  {
   case 0:
   //dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0] =  get image 0
   break;
   //case 1:
   //case 2:
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

1. You are working on VS2010 C# ASP.NET 4
2. Your ico files are in a folder resides the website home directory (~/Images/)

If you have your original table is of the form:

```
CREATE TABLE YourOriginalTable(
    [PK] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [TheByteVariable] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SomeOtherTextColumn] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL);
```

with data like:

```
INSERT YourOriginalTable VALUES
(0,'Jon'),
(2,'Joan'),
(1,'John'),
(0,'Jonnie'),
(2,'Jonny');
```

You can use the following in your aspx file:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="PK,gvImageCode" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PK" HeaderText="PK" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PK"  Visible="False"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="gvImageCode" HeaderText="gvImageCode" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="gvImageCode" Visible="False" />
            <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="gvImageFileName" HeaderText="i" ></asp:ImageField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SomeOtherTextColumn" HeaderText="SomeOtherTextColumn" SortExpression="SomeOtherTextColumn" />

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:YourConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="DECLARE @tb TABLE([gvImageCode] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,[gvImageFileName] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL);
                       INSERT @tb VALUES (0, N'~/Images/Red.ico'),(1, N'~/Images/Green.ico'),(2, N'~/Images/Yellow.ico');
                       SELECT PK, gvImageFileName, SomeOtherTextColumn, gvImageCode FROM YourOriginalTable INNER JOIN @tb ON TheByteVariable = gvImageCode">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The solution is to be found in the `SelectCommand`.
You can see there creating a table with the URL of the ico files and joining it to the original table.

Attention:

1. asp:ImageField of the GridView is not a regular column.
2. DataKeyNames of the GridView, both keys must be there.
3. Keys and all displayed columns must appear in the `SELECT` clause.
4. In order to hide a column use: `Visible="False"`

Tested!

I hope it helps